# QImage from HBITMAP

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qtgui, hbitmap

In my windows-only program, I use a third-party library, which returns a `HBITMAP`.

Is there a way to initialize a `QImage` from its contents, i.e. to convert it to a `QImage`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the way to do it for Qt 4 (QtGui):

```
QImage image(QPixmap::fromWinHBITMAP(hBitmap).toImage());
```

This is the way to do it for Qt 5 (QtWinExtras):

```
QPixmap pixmap = QtWin::fromHBITMAP(hBitmap);
QImage image = pixmap.toImage();

// or

QtWin::imageFromHBITMAP(hdc, hBitmap, width, height)
```

Comment: For Qt 6 `fromWinHBITMAP` is now part of `QImage` natively, so you can just call `QImage.fromHBITMAP`.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this seems to work for me:

```
QImage image(QPixmap::fromWinHBITMAP(hBitmap).toImage());
```

Comment: This is not available after Qt 4.8

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 without Extras:
Put before your code

```
#include <QPixmap>
Q_GUI_EXPORT QPixmap qt_pixmapFromWinHBITMAP(HBITMAP bitmap, int hbitmapFormat=0);
```

and in your function, for example

```
QPixmap pixmap = qt_pixmapFromWinHBITMAP(LoadBitmap(uiID));
```

Cheers

Comment: This is not a public API.

Answer (score 1):

[As of Qt 6.0](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/whatsnew60.html), you could use the *static* [QImage::fromHBITMAP(HBITMAP hbitmap)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#fromHBITMAP):

> Returns a [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html) that is equivalent to the given hbitmap.
>
> HBITMAP does not store information about the alpha channel.
>
> In the standard case, the alpha channel is ignored and a fully opaque image is created (typically of >format [QImage::Format_RGB32](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#Format-enum)).
>
> There are cases where the alpha channel is used, though, for example for application icon or systray icons. In that case, **reinterpretAsFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32)** should be called on the returned image to ensure the format is correct.
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 6.0.